# Interpolate a CDF to get an interpolated hazard rate, or interpolate the hazard rate directly?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, interpolation, numerics, numerical-models

My problem is that I need to do an interpolation. Eventually, I will work on the hazard rate, but I do not know if it is better to interpolate the CDF or the hazard rate. Let me explain better.

I've a CDF evaluated at certain points. I numerically differentiate it over the points (`diff` function in R) to get the pdf. I'm interested in computing the inverse hazard rate ($\frac{1-F(x)}{f(x)}$) and to have it over a broader set of values $y$.

Is it better to interpolate the CDF $F(x)$ over the broader set of values $y$, (that is, interpolate $F(x)$ over $y$ and then compute the pdf and inverse hazard rate over $y$), or to interpolate the hazard rate directly in the end? 
Also, which is the best interpolation procedure?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you interested in estimating the inverse hazard rate? This will help guide an answer.

Comment: I'm estimating a model by taking the GMM of the first order conditions and the inverse hazard rate enters linearly in the FOC.

Comment: When you say you have a CDF evaluated at several points, do you mean the Kaplan Meier curves (or if not censored, EDF?) Because then using numerical differentiation is going to be very problematic. If you are using a parametric model, this is very reasonable.